# Как обособить оборот "читай..." в тексте? Например, " ..он был нездоров...читай болен..."

Tags: пунктуация

Как обособить оборот "читай..." в тексте? Например, " ..он был нездоров...читай болен..."

Answer (score 2):

он был нездоров (читай: болен)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?